# Android Studio: refresh preview on picture change

Tags: android-studio, preview

I'm using Android Studio 1.0.2 and Gimp as external editor for the images.
When I want to modify an image, I select it, click on "Jump to external editor", apply changes, save it, go back to Android Studio and... close/open project to refresh the changes.

Is there a shortcut for this ? I cannot find any "refresh preview".
Even if I recompile, start the app, close/reopen the preview, I cannot see the changes on the preview (only on the execute app).

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's really easy, indeed... didn't notice the button.
In the preview panel, upper right corner (on the right of the + and - buttons), there's a refresh button.